# Summing up elements of nested lists based on conditions from another list

Tags: list-manipulation, map

Here is a simplified version of my question, nothing that I have a much larger dataset.

I have a list of samples of proportions:

```
samples = {{0.1, 0.5, 0.4}, {0.3, 0.3, 0.4}, {0.3, 0.6, 0.1}}
```

and a mapping that corresponds to what each element of each sample refers to (assume they are years):

```
mapping = {1999, 2000, 2001}
```

I want to return the share of observations for each sample that are greater than 2000.
I am trying to use MapThread. I can do each sample separately:

```
Total[MapThread[If[#1 > 2000, 0, #2] &, {mapping, samples[[1]]}]]
Total[MapThread[If[#1 > 2000, 0, #2] &, {mapping, samples[[2]]}]]
Total[MapThread[If[#1 > 2000, 0, #2] &, {mapping, samples[[3]]}]]
```

> 0.6
>
> 0.6
>
> 0.9

Is there a way to return this in one line, and in one list like:

> {0.6, 0.6, 0.9}

Comment: If you use Thread[{mapping, Transpose[samples]}] you get {{1999, {0.1, 0.3, 0.3}}, {2000, {0.5, 0.3, 0.6}}, {2001, {0.4, 0.4, 
   0.1}}} and could use Select to pick out those years greater than 2000.  You can then transpose back if you want.

Comment: Please provide the data for `states` and make sure your code runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function that can be `Map`ped to `samples`:

```
f = Total[MapThread[If[#1 > 2000, 0, #2] &, {mapping, #}]] &
f /@ samples
```

> {0.6, 0.6, 0.9}

A few additional alternatives:

```
samples.UnitStep[2000 - mapping]
```

> {0.6, 0.6, 0.9}

```
mask = Boole[# <= 2000] & /@ mapping; 
(* or  mask = UnitStep[2000 - mapping] *)
Total[Pick[samples, mask & /@ samples, 1], {2}]
(* alternatively, Total[Pick[#, mask, 1]] & /@ samples *)
```

> {0.6, 0.6, 0.9}

```
assoc = AssociationThread[mapping -> #] & /@ samples
Total@*KeySelect[# <= 2000 &] /@ assoc
```

> {0.6, 0.6, 0.9}